# I can't select the spaces while typing, it gets into a white cell

Tags: python, spyder

In python and its derivative applications (currently spyder) it does not allow me to select spaces or between characters while typing, instead it encloses the letters in a white cell and I cannot understand exactly where the cursor has selected. Is there any chance I can change it as a flat bar to its default settings?[my status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VyT3.png)
[thats what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VA3Mm.png)

i looked tools>preferences and web but did'nt see any solution about that

Comment: Guessing here: try hitting the Insert key.

Comment: Although if that's a terminal window instead of an editor window, that's just how cursors normally look in a terminal. You might be able to change it in your IDE or terminal emulator settings

Comment: @user2357112 it really worked, how simple thanks!